# Numbers average example

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm wondering is there different way you would do the below code?

I'm learning C++ programming and as part of dynamic memory examples I did the below example.

It is a program that gives the average of numbers as they are input.

I'm hoping if I could see some different ways to do this I can learn better. It doesn't have to be using dynamic memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int* numbers;
    cout << " q'to exit. s to continue:";
    char selection;
    cin >> selection;
    int numbergiven;
    int* temp;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; selection != 'Q'; i++) {
        int counter = 0;
        cout << " Give me a number:";
        cin >> numbergiven;
        numbers = new int[i];
        copy(temp, temp + i - 1, numbers);
        *(numbers + i - 1) = numbergiven;
        int sum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            sum = sum + *(numbers + j);
            counter++;
        }
        int average = sum / (counter);
        cout << "Average so far is:" << average << endl;
        cout << "q'to exit. s to continue:";
        cin >> selection;
        temp = new int[i];
        copy(numbers, numbers + i, temp);
        delete[] numbers;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would start with a std::vector and not do any of these copies. Also for average you do not need to remember the values unless you want to print them at the end.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you don't need the individual numbers for anything other than the averaging itself you can eliminate the numbers and temp array and be left without a need for any dynamoc memory By maintaining a running sum and count.

Psuedocode:

```
var userInput
var sum
var count
var average

userInput = readInput ()
while ( userInput != Q)
{
    sum += userInput
    count++
    userInput = readInput ()
    average = sum/count
}
```